# sqoop add timestamp to hive partition value

Tags: hive, sqoop

To import as400 table to hive partitioned with timestamp. i add two arguments:

```
--hive-partition-key "time"
```

for the name partition column, and for the map partition value:

```
--hive-partition-value "2018-05-01"
```

my question is how to add a query in the hive-partition-value 
for example:

```
$timestamp=select now() as timestamp from mytable
--hive-partition-value $timestamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date` command:

```
 current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Then:

```
sqoop import --hive-partition-key "time" --hive-partition-value "$current_date" ...
```